# Iterating over multiple <ul> items to make a jQuery script work without repeating code

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, magicline

I have implemented a jQuery 'magic line' in my multi-level navigation menu and it seems to work with the first sub-navigation, but if I add more it breaks.

**My question is**: How do I iterate over the other sub-navigation menus to get it to work across however many sub-level items I may add? ( `<ul class="sy__list__secondary">` )

Please take a look at my code below. To reproduce my problem follow these steps:

1. Hover over the first child in the main navigation (HOME)
2. Then hover over the children of the 'HOME' item - **the magic line will work perfectly.**
3. Now hover over the second child in the main navigation (ABOUT)
4. Then hover over the children of the 'ABOUT' list - **the magic line will not work.**

My question is: How do I iterate over the other sub-navigation menus to get it to work across however many sub-level items I may add?

```js
var $el, leftPos, newWidth;

$('.sy__list__secondary').each(function() {
  $(this).append("<li id='magic-line'></li>");
});

/* Cache it */
var $magicLine = $("#magic-line");

function magicLinePref() {
  $magicLine
    .width($(".sy__list__secondary.active li:first-child").width())
    .css("left", $(".sy__list__secondary.active li:first-child").position().left)
    .data("origLeft", $magicLine.position().left)
    .data("origWidth", $magicLine.width());

  $(".sy__list__secondary li").find("a").hover(function() {
    $el = $(this);
    leftPos = $el.position().left;
    newWidth = $el.parent().width();
    $magicLine.stop().animate({
      left: leftPos,
      width: newWidth
    });
  }, function() {
    $magicLine.stop().animate({
      left: $magicLine.data("origLeft"),
      width: $magicLine.data("origWidth")
    });
  });
}

$('.sy__list__primary > li').hover(function() {
  magicLinePref();
});
```

```css
.sy__navigation {
  position: relative;
}

.sy__navigation__primary {
  background: #333333;
}

.sy__navigation__secondary {
  position: absolute;
  background: #031f37eb;
  left: 0;
  top: 50px;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
}

#magic-line {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 0 !important;
  left: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #31B2E7;
}

.sy__list__primary>li:hover .sy__navigation__secondary {
  display: block;
}

ul.sy__list__secondary {
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  color: #ffffff;
}

ul.sy__list__primary {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul.sy__list__primary span,
a {
  color: #ffffff;
}

ul.sy__list__primary li {
  display: inline-block;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul.sy__list__primary>li {
  padding: 20px;
}

ul.sy__list__secondary li a {
  padding: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css">

<div class="sy__navigation">
  <div class="sy__navigation__primary">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <ul class="sy__list__primary">
          <li><span>HOME</span>
            <div class="sy__navigation__secondary">
              <ul class="sy__list__secondary active">
                <li><a href="#">SUB 1A</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SUB 1A</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SUB 1A</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li><span>ABOUT</span>
            <div class="sy__navigation__secondary">
              <ul class="sy__list__secondary">
                <li><a href="#">SUB 2A</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SUB 2A</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SUB 2A</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </li>

        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated `magicLinePref()` function and passed respective `li` object. Fetched `.sy__list__secondary` and `.#magic-line` using `li.find`.

Removed global declaration of `var $magicLine = $("#magic-line");`. As when jQuery select any object with id selector `#` it will only return first object found with given id.

Instead of that I have select element which are inside current `li` element which is passing from `magicLinePref($(this));`.

`li.find("#magic-line");` find element with id `magic-line` inside current `li`. Similarly for class selector `.sy__list__secondary`.

```js
var $el, leftPos, newWidth;

$('.sy__list__secondary').each(function() {
  $(this).append("<li id='magic-line'></li>");
});

/* Cache it */

function magicLinePref(li) {
var $magicLine = li.find("#magic-line");
  $magicLine
    .width(li.find(".sy__list__secondary li:first-child").width())
    .css("left", li.find(".sy__list__secondary li:first-child").position().left)
    .data("origLeft", $magicLine.position().left)
    .data("origWidth", $magicLine.width());

  li.find(".sy__list__secondary li").find("a").hover(function() {
    $el = $(this);
    leftPos = $el.position().left;
    newWidth = $el.parent().width();
    $magicLine.stop().animate({
      left: leftPos,
      width: newWidth
    });
  }, function() {
    $magicLine.stop().animate({
      left: $magicLine.data("origLeft"),
      width: $magicLine.data("origWidth")
    });
  });
}

$('.sy__list__primary > li').hover(function() {
  magicLinePref($(this));
});
```

```css
.sy__navigation {
  position: relative;
}

.sy__navigation__primary {
  background: #333333;
}

.sy__navigation__secondary {
  position: absolute;
  background: #031f37eb;
  left: 0;
  top: 50px;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
}

#magic-line {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 0 !important;
  left: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #31B2E7;
}

.sy__list__primary>li:hover .sy__navigation__secondary {
  display: block;
}

ul.sy__list__secondary {
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  color: #ffffff;
}

ul.sy__list__primary {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul.sy__list__primary span,
a {
  color: #ffffff;
}

ul.sy__list__primary li {
  display: inline-block;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul.sy__list__primary>li {
  padding: 20px;
}

ul.sy__list__secondary li a {
  padding: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css">

<div class="sy__navigation">
  <div class="sy__navigation__primary">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <ul class="sy__list__primary">
          <li><span>HOME</span>
            <div class="sy__navigation__secondary">
              <ul class="sy__list__secondary">
                <li><a href="#">SUB 1A</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SUB 1A</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SUB 1A</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li><span>ABOUT</span>
            <div class="sy__navigation__secondary">
              <ul class="sy__list__secondary">
                <li><a href="#">SUB 2A</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SUB 2A</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SUB 2A</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </li>

        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This fixed my problem, could you however explain in steps each change you made and why? This will help me understand it better

Comment: @zxynz Explain my changes in more detail.